# Why does liferay published unedited specific journal article?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1. I have many journal articles(Web content). When I publish to remote server. Liferay publish one specific article despite no changes in it. I have written Listener on journal article.

Comment: Snappy reply: It's probably because of *something*. More seriously: How should we guess from two lines of question that don't even give the exact version of Liferay? We'll need some steps to reproduce - with the steps that you don't give, my answer is "works for me (TM)"

Comment: Olaf Thanks for comment                                                                              It is liferay problem sir. If we place journal article on web content display portlet and place one particular page e.g. Home page. If we publish on remote server with selecting the home page it will publish that webcontent as well despite no change in it. I had written listener on journal article and logic for particular type of webcontent which took 7 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is liferay problem. If we place journal article on web content display portlet and place on particular page e.g. Home page. If we publish on remote server with selecting the home page It will publish that webcontent as well despite no change in it.

The webcontent will not publish if you select any other page and publish If you not updated that webcontent.